# Displaying tracks using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, bounding-box, matlab-cvst

I am currently trying to track head using MATLAB. Currently at each frame I have bounding boxes of heads, where each set of heads throughout the frame correspond to a unique ID (of a unique person). In a frame a bbox can only be correlated with 1 person.

**Question :** After setting IDs to the bounding boxes, can someone explain to me how I can plot a track using MATLAB please? Ideally the track should pass from the centre of a person's bounding box to the next.

Comment: append new points to the trajectory array and keep plotting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `insertMarker` function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox to mark the centers of the bounding boxes.

Comment: Hi Dima thanks for your response. I have added a new question which is related to your implementation. Would you be able to answer it for me please? I appreciate. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201984/kanade-lucas-tomasi-tracker)