# Kanade Lucas Tomasi Tracker

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, tracking, matlab-cvst

I was looking into Kanade Lucas Tomasi Tracker in the [following link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47105-detect-and-track-multiple-faces/content/MultiObjectTrackerKLT.m). However, I was wondering how the KLT recognizes the new people have entered scene. I know that there is replenishing of bounding boxes every 10 frames, but in case a person say entered in the 5th frame. Does it mean the for his first 5th consecutive frames the person is not captured? If I understand that this threshold can be varied, however there will still be cases when this will happen whats so ever.

Can someone explain if I am getting this wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. A new person will not be detected until the next time `vision.CascadeObjectDetector` is run. This example essentially assumes that when new people enter the field of view, they will stay visible for some time, and will be detected eventually.

It may be helpful to think about it in relation to the frame rate. If the code runs at 10 fps, then the re-detection occurs every second. In other words, it will take on the order of a second for a new face to be detected. If that is not acceptable, then you can try re-detecting more often. The thing to keep in mind, though, is that face detection is slower than KLT (`vision.PointTracker`), so if you run the face detector more often, your frame rate will decrease.

Comment: Thanks for your great response (as always). I understand your point, so in my case since I have a v low framerate say 4f/s I need to replenish every 4 frames. So if I am understanding correctly you are making an assumption that new people will enter scene, every second. Am I right? And to add to this question, how do you recommend that I associate the bboxes to the same person after replenishing please? Is there a standard KLT way?

Comment: Not quite. The assumption is that 1 second is short enough for KLT not to lose any objects, and also that 1 second is not too long of a delay for detecting a new person. As far as associating the detected bboxes to the tracked bboxes, it is not really a part of KLT.  Using the overlap seems like a reasonable thing to do. The typical measures used in many papers are the ratio of intersection  to the union of the boxes and the ratio of the smaller box area to the union. See `bboxOverlapRatio` function.

Comment: I understand @Dima. Thanks for your kind information. So probably I cannot use it to compare with the tracker I am implementing. By any chance do you know of any multi-person tracker which I can use in MATLAB so as to be used for comparison? Say for example a particle filtering one? Thanks Dima